# Replacing string in dropdown menu

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

So im trying to load a different string when the user has selected a different item, my code:

```
void ModeSelectorSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var data1 = new string[]
    {
        "January 2012",
        "February 2012",
        "March 2012",
        "April 2012",
    };

    var data2 = new string[]
    {
         "Married",
         "Divorced",
         "Buy new house",
         "Get promotion",
    };

    if (_Menu2.SelectedIndex == 2) 
    {
        _Menu3.ItemsSource = data1;     
    }

    else 

    if (_Menu2.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {

        _Menu3.ItemsSource = data2;
    }
}
```

When I use just 1 string it works fine, but as soon as I try to load 2 different strings in the same drop down menu it shuts down, meaning that its not showing any string data at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check whether your control(of which the selected index has to be checked) causes a postback. If so, rebind the drop down menu.

Comment: @RohitKiran No clue how to do that.

Comment: Are you trying to load data from data1 and data2 into a single drop down. Please be specific.

Comment: Here u are taking _Menu3.ItemsSource. Is this datagrid or something else?

Comment: @RohitKiran "I try to load 2 different strings in the same drop down", Yes I am.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET WebForms DropDownList follow this code snippet:

```
_Menu3.DataSource = someData;
_Menu3.DataBind();
```

Perhaps it would be better to move this logic on a client side and use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It's work for me and AutoPostBack will be true for _Menu2.

```
protected void ModeSelectorSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data1 = new string[]
                                    {
                                    "January 2012",
                                    "February 2012",
                                    "March 2012",
                                    "April 2012",
                                    };

    var data2 = new string[]
                                    {
                                    "Married",
                                    "Divorced",
                                    "Buy new house",
                                    "Get promotion",
                                    };
    if (_Menu2.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        _Menu3.DataSource = data1;
        _Menu3.DataBind();

    }
    else if (_Menu2.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {

        _Menu3.DataSource = data2;
        _Menu3.DataBind();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Im developing for a microsoft Pixelsense using Surface 2.0 SDK. People suggested using ItemsSource, im getting errors using DataSource and DataBind saying that I miss a reference, but no clue which one.

Comment: @Tarayaa you should be specific in your question. here i am using visual studio 2010 according to your question tag.

Comment: Oh and im also using visual studio 2010

Comment: ok, try this code in visual studio 2010. It will work and remember AutoPostBack will be true for _Menu2.

Comment: Its still telling me that its missing a reference

Comment: can you tell me what type of reference u r getting.

Comment: Its telling me it can't find databind and datasource, if it was telling me the type I could add it.

Comment: ok, which tool are taking for _Menu3 means r u taking dropdown list for _menu3.

Comment: Dont understand the question.

Comment: r u assign data1 variable value to dropdown list because datasource and databind both are property of dropdown list.

Comment: No its being assigned to ListBox

Comment: Please changed listbox to dropdownlist box.let me know Is it work.

Comment: If I answered of ur question. Plz except my answer.